# rewrite rule if iphone?

Tags: apache, iphone

just need one url on my site to check if its a mobile device and then rerite the url accordingly.

want to rewrite;
/play-reel/miranda-bowen/playpeaches-and-cream
to
/**mobile**/play-reel/miranda-bowen/playpeaches-and-cream

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPhone.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^play-reel(.*)\$ mobile/play-reel$1 [R=302,NC]  

RewriteRule ^mobile/play-reel/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ play-reel-new-html5-02.php?director=$1&video=$2 [L]
# the 3rd line works but cant get the url to change for it to be picked up
```

can anyone see what's wrong? There's no erro

best, Dan

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the code you’ve provided in the answer.  I’m not sure, but it might look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^play-reel(.*)\$ mobile/play-reel/$1/$2 [R=302,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

this works but doesn't modify the visible url

RewriteRule ^play-reel(.*)\$ play-reel-new-html5-02.php?director=$1&video=$2 [L]